# Integrating VFR Reader into PhoneGap project

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to integrate PDF Reader in my app build with PhoneGap, [VFR Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) is native, written in obj-c, anyone has tried to play with this?
My pdfs would be loaded from the server, so how can i pass with a pdf as parameter with JS to VFR?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as a PhoneGap plugin!

[Here's the discussion thread and the solution sourcecode](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/-JTVuXmP_ro/8qkD19tT4k8J)...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, i have tried that. It's what i'm looking for, but i never got it work, i get a bunch of errors, don't know where from.